# стандартные блоки PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Возможно ли и если да, то как, изменить стиль стандартных блоков PrimeFaces?
Интересует конкретно компонент `p:accordionPanel`. Шрифт текста в них и цвет этих блоков.

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно. Во-первых, можно менять тему целиком, варианты бесплатных тем есть [здесь](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml).

Если требуется изменить какой-то конкретный компонент, то вам поможет отладчик браузера и знание `CSS`. В отладчике выбираем нужный компонент и смотрим его `HTML` и стили. Для `p:accordionPanel` корневым тегом является `div`, которому присвоен стиль с именем `ui-accordion`. Добавляем на страницу свои стили, которые изменяют стили Primefaces, вот пример изменения шрифта компонента и цвета панели с содержимым компонента:

```
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <p:accordionPanel>
            <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                    <h:outputText value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..."/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Godfather Part II">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                    <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..."/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </h:form>

    <style type="text/css">
        #mainForm .ui-accordion {
            font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        }
        #mainForm .ui-accordion-content {
            background-color: aliceblue;
        }
    </style>
```

`#mainForm .ui-accordion` - это путь, сообщающий браузеру о том, что все элементы, имеющие стиль `.ui-accordion` и находящиеся внутри элемента с идентификатором `mainForm`, теперь получают указанный стиль. Такой путь нужен для того, чтобы не затронуть остальные `p:accordionPanel`-ы на странице. Если хотите, чтобы изменение стиля затронуло все `p:accordionPanel`-ы в приложении, то `#mainForm` следует убрать, вынести стиль в отдельный CSS-файл и импортировать его на вашу страницу (лучше всего это сделать в шаблоне, который должны использовать все страницы сайта).

Применяя подобный подход, можно менять любые компоненты PrimeFaces. Если что-то не будет получаться, скорее всего разбираться надо будет в CSS, а не в PrimeFaces.